# Chrome/Edge extension with current time as tab-title

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

How can I develop a Chrome/Edge extension that always displays the current time in the tab title before the actual title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Create new folder "time2tab".

2.) Put new file "manifest.js" in it:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "time2tab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A simple Chrome extension that changes the title of the current tab to the current timestamp.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

3.) Put new file "content.js" in it:

```
var originalTitel = document.title;
  
function updateTime() {
  
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  var tenthOfASecond = Math.floor(now.getMilliseconds() / 100);
  
  var timeString = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0') + '.' + tenthOfASecond.toString();
  
  document.title = timeString + " " + originalTitel;
  
}
 
setInterval(updateTime, 100);
```

4.) Aktivate Developer mode in Extensions-Tab. Load the folder via Load unpacked.

Use cases for this extension:

- This extension can be used as a minimal working example for developing a Chrome/Edge extension.
- It can also be used to record the current time in a screencast recording an automated test.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `chrome.tabs` API to get the current tab and update its title with the current time.

Here's a sample code snippet that you can use as a starting point:

```js
// background.js

function updateTabTitle(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
    var currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    var newTitle = currentTime + " - " + tab.title;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "document.title = '" + newTitle + "';"});
  });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    updateTabTitle(tabId);
  }
});
```

This code listens for the `tabs.onUpdated` event, which is fired when a tab is updated (e.g. when a page finishes loading). When this event is fired, the `updateTabTitle` function is called with the `tabId` of the updated tab. This function gets the current time, constructs a new title string with the current time and the original tab title, and updates the tab's title using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

Note that this code only updates the tab title when the page finishes loading. If you want to update the title more frequently (e.g. every second), you can use `setInterval` to call `updateTabTitle` at regular intervals.

Also note that in manifest v3, the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` method requires the `scripting` permission to be explicitly granted in the manifest file. Here's an example of how to include this permission in your manifest:

```json
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting"
  ]
}
```

For more information on the `chrome.tabs` API and the `scripting` permission, see the following links:

- [chrome.tabs API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/)
- [scripting permission documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/#scripting)